# Can I use XML::Simple with an in-memory string, rather than a file?

Tags: perl, xml-simple

[XML::Simple documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Simple) says to initiate the data structure with an XML file, using `XMLin('[FILENAME]')` ... but I have an in-memory string.

Can I use it directly, or do I need to save it to the filesystem and then load it into `XMLin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have missed [in said documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Simple) the following information:

> XMLin() accepts an optional XML
>   specifier followed by zero or more
>   `'name => value'` option pairs. The XML
>   specifier can be one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> A string of XML
>
> A string containing XML (recognised by
>   the presence of `'<'` and `'>'`
>   characters) will be parsed directly.
>   eg:
>
> ```
>   $ref = XMLin('<opt username="bob" password="flurp" />');
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It also says

```
my $ref = $xs->XMLin([<xml file or string>] [, <options>]);
```